# Use of third party wrappers like file://

Tags: ruby, sinatra

With the aim of setting up a lab, I am in the process of doing tests with Sinatra :

```rb
require 'sinatra'
require 'open-uri'

get '/' do
  format 'RESPONSE: %s', open(params[:url]).read
end
```

It works if I use the HTTP wrapper like `http://localhost:4567/?url=https://www.google.com` but I'm surprised that it doesn't work with other wrappers like `file://` to try for example `http://localhost:4567/?url=file:///etc/passwd`.

On my system I can of course do `curl file:///etc/passwd` and it works.

Any idea ?

Thank's

Comment: open should work if you remove the preceeding `file://` from any file tag.  have you tried it without that URI code?

Comment: Yes it works, but in fact I wanted to use the `gopher://` wrapper which is not usable as it is.
I couldn't find a way to use this wrapper with open-uri.

Comment: From the (OpenURI) [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.2/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/URI.html#open-method): _"We can accept URIs and strings that begin with http://, https:// and ftp://."_

Comment: https://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-net-text/versions/ ... seems very beta, but is being actively worked upon. untested ... https://git.umaneti.net/ruby-net-text/log/?h=support-gopher